# Python does not create .txt file

Tags: python, docker, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I have a python script that takes an array of `BeautifulSoup` tags, loops through them and prints the `text` property of each tag, as well as writing it to a .txt file. Unfortunately, this .txt file never gets created. This is my code:

```
with open('output/scrape.txt', 'a+') as text_file:
for headline in soup.select('#top-news span[class*="headline"]'):
    text_file.write(headline.text)
    print(headline.text)
```

The print statement is working, but the attempt to create and write to the file is not. I've tried a simpler write operation, and that doesn't work either:

```
text_file = open("output/scrape.txt", "a+")
text_file.write("Test")
text_file.close()
```

The `output` folder exists as you can see here:

[image: Folder structure]

...and I've confirmed the folder allows reading and writing:

[image: Folder permissions`]

The script is executed from a Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.2-slim
WORKDIR /src
RUN pip install --upgrade -v pip \
        lxml \
        requests \
        beautifulsoup4
COPY ./scrape.py .
RUN mkdir -p /src/output
CMD python scrape.py
```

Comment: Are the pics you've provided from outside or inside the Docker container? If the script is running inside the container and the volume is not shared then it is just creating files inside the container which are not ordinarily visible from the host.

Comment: Your "simpler" write operation is creating the file and writing to it just fine for me

Comment: how are you executing the code? are you sure you are in the right directory? you can use `import os; os.getcwd()` to check

Comment: @HoxhaAlban The script is being executed by a docker file when the container runs. I am inside this directory when I build the docker image and run the container. I added those statements into this script but I don't see it giving me that information anywhere.

Comment: @lgflorentino those pictures are from outside the container... my local hard drive. `myName/projects/scrape`. The pic is the contents of that folder. I added the contents of the Dockerfile that runs the script for reference.

Comment: @Pigpocket sorry my bad, you need to put `os.getcwd()` inside a `print`

Comment: @Pigpocket Are you able to `docker exec -it <container-name> /bin/bash` and run the command manually inside the container to confirm it creates the files inside the container ?

Comment: @HoxhaAlban that prints out `/src`

Answer (score 1):

The `Dockerfile` you have provided copies the `./scrape.py` script into the container. But it does not share any files between your container and your host computer. You will need to set up a way of sharing the files that get created inside your container with your host. This is usually with the use of Volumes or bind mounts. [Docker Use Volumes Doc](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

Answer (score 0):

My command to mount a volume to the container when I run it had the incorrect directory. I was using `docker run -v output:/output nuprizm` when I should've been using `docker run -v output:/src/output nuprizm`.